# Profiling WebMethods services?

Tags: service, soa, webmethods

What techniques are available to profile services running in WebMethods Integration Server?

That is, to obtain data which would indicate which parts would benefit most from optimisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the 'Service Profiler for webMethods Integration Server' from http://www.wrightia.com/serviceprofiler.html

Comment: This is what I was hoping to find! (If the "accept answer" button was here, I'd use it).

Now to fix the glibc dependencies it needs :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of trying [webMUnit](http://webmunit.sourceforge.net)?
You could add time logging around certain method calls to get an idea of how long things are taking to execute. However, the time logging itself will add overhead too, so just keep that in mind.

Or possibly memory profilers such as YourKit Profiler, JProfiler, JProbe etc? Im not sure about these, as I've never used them myself, but they might help by letting you know what's taking up a lot of memory etc

Answer (score 1):

Another tool which will do it is Green Hat tester which is a commercial tool used for testing webMethods. If you use the reporting capabilities of that when running tests you get profiling information generated..

António Abreu's linked tool is a more dedicated profiling tool however and would be the simplest solution.

If you want an "out of the box" solution you could turn on service auditing for the called services and do the legwork yourself, but that's a bit of manual effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can find here a new monitoring tool for IS services: [Rich Statistics](http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/web/guest/pwiki/-/wiki/Main/RichStatistics+-+how+to+easly+monitor+the+service+activity+on+your+Integration+Server)

Answer (score 0):

I was involved only in development phase so i dont know details but our system was tested with heavy load-testing and hardware was monitored during the process, it actually gave some feedback about bottlenecks. JMeter and sar were used.